# Proper forward secrecy

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

Currently I have a protocol using a simple RSA to AES handshake. I have been reading more and more and would like to implement proper forward secrecy, but at the same time I'd like to improve the performance on mobile devices.

My question is, where would I start reading / learning about how to implement proper ECDHE ( as this seems to be the preferred choice ) and how to properly implement it?

The documentation on OpenSSL seems to be rather unfinished and annoying to work with.

Comment: Is this for production use?

Comment: @SEJPM yes, I will have a security audit on my implementation very soon but I'd still like to implement these extra features some day.

Comment: In this case I'd strongly recommend against implementing ECDH yourself. You can use OpenSSL or some other well-known library (like Gutmann's cryptlib) to either provide the primitive or even better let the library provide you with TLS to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to read those two documents:

1. [RFC 6090: Fundamental Elliptic Curve Cryptography Algorithms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6090) - describes all the fundamental operations in ECC algorithms (including ECDH), and includes references to further readings with more details.
2. [The security impact of a new cryptographic library](https://cr.yp.to/highspeed/coolnacl-20120725.pdf) - explains design and implementation decisions behind NaCl, an OpenSSL alternative from Daniel J. Bernstein.

Comment: One of the bigger problems is that NaCL will not be able to take advantage of hardware accelerated AES on the embedded client devices  ( This usually is only invoked at 4k bytes or more, but that will actually happen at times in my use case )

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt I'd switch from AES to ChaCha20 anyway, as it's not susceptible to related-key attack (not a big threat, but still a flaw in AES). You might also want to take a look at [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium), fork of NaCl actively developed by Frank Denis.

Comment: I actually used it already in a test implementation, since after building NaCL it seemed to not be able to find randombytes ( and coz of constraints I could not include those source files directly into my project very easily ), and though i'm sure I messed up somewhere along the lines of either installing or compiling, libsodium simply did not have this issue. And how secure could one consider ChaCha20, isn't it usually considered bad practice to use relatively 'new' algs?

Comment: ChaCha20 was published in 2008, and no serious flaw was found since then. It's secure enough to become standardized by IETF (as [RFC 7539](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7539)) and adopted by organizations like [Google](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/04/speeding-up-and-strengthening-https.html), [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1247860) and [CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/do-the-chacha-better-mobile-performance-with-cryptography/). It will be [included in OpenSSL 1.1.0](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/304), too.